# Using Canopy as a Python distribution, where is "canopy_cli.exe" located?

Tags: python, python-2.7, canopy, python-venv

I am working with Canopy for Python, which is a software bundle of Python 2.7 and the most important data analysis packages. It also includes IPython and makes working in a live console very easy.

Instead of using virtualenv, Canopy makes use of a Python-2.7-backported version of "venv". To initially setup a new environment, they want me to use `canopy_cli myProjectFolder`.

Unfortunately, I do not find a `canopy_cli.exe` in my `C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App` on Windows.

Did I do anything wrong or is the file located elsewhere?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found it, `canopy_cli.exe` exactly at the specified location, so the directory is correct.

So... Maybe you try to reinstall the software?

Btw, what version you are using? How about updating as the same time?

Comment: Hi Ray, my Canopy version is `1.0.3`. I updated to `1.0.5`. I'll try to reinstall it later. Thank you!

Comment: Reinstalling Canopy with the latest version solved the problem.

Comment: Yes, there is no canopy_cli in 1.0.3. It was introduced in 1.1